# How does a set $G=\{0,1\}$ satisfies the inverse property with respect to addition?

Tags: group-theory

Like if we say that in this set identity element is $0$. So, inverse of any element of $G$ is a number that if we add in the that element, it gives result zero :
                            $$1+(x)= 0$$       where $x$ is the inverse of $1$.

What I think is $x$ should be $-1$, which is not in the set. So, it doesn't  fullfil the $4$th condition of a group. So, it is not a group but in my exam question, the right answer was group. How is that? Where am I wrong?

Comment: If addition is done mod $2$, then $1+1=0$. In other words, working mod $2$, we have $1 = -1$.

Answer (score 4):

A group is not a set. A group is a set *together with* a binary operation on that set, that satisfies certain axioms. So asking whether $G=\{0,1\}$ is a group is meaningless, unless we also *define* what the sum of two elements should be.

To answer your question about the exam question we need to know *exactly* what the question was. Word for word.

Comment: I told you earlier that it is with respect to addition. (G,+)

Comment: The question was if G={0,1} under operation (+). Tell whether G is a group under addition ?

Comment: Actually no, you didn't say that. I find it hard to believe that the question literally read that way, if they're claiming the answer is yes. For the answer to be yes they must have said "addition modulo 2" or simply _defined_ $0+0=0$, $0+1=1+0=1$, $1+1=2$. If the question _was_ _exactly_ as you say then the answer is of course $G$ is not a group under addition, it's not even closed under addition, because $1+1=2\notin G$.

Comment: I look at the solution of that question. The table that was drawn next to the question shows that  1+1=0 and the inverse of 1 was shown as 1 like                                          1+1=0

Comment: Aha - then the statement of the problem was not exactly as you claimed! That table is part of the problem -  instead of asking why $G$ is a group under addition you should have asked why $G$ is a group under the addition defined by that table.

Comment: Oh now I got it. I was thinking that you cannot defined 
it by yourself. Can we say that it is a set of residues of module 2?